# Export WPF DataGrid to text file preserving all formatting

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I would have thought this was simple but I can't find any obvious way of doing it!

I have a WPF DataGrid that is bound to an Access database. I want to be able to export the content of the DataGrid to a tab-delimited text file including the column headers and preserving all formatting. This should be exactly equivalent to selecting all the rows of the DataGrid, and then copy and pasting into an empty text file.

I could get the data from my view, but I have gone to some effort to getting all the numerical formatting exactly right in the DataGrid.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by formatting? text files don't have formatting. Word documents, for example, do.

Comment: I mean numeric formatting - some of the columns are in scientific format, some have fixed numbers of places. This is dynamic, so I'd really like to get this from the DataGrid. Essentially I want the text in the DataGrid in my text file exactly as it is.